# Apply styles on div when another div overlaps

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have two divs. `Div1` and `Div2`. `Div1` is a fixed div with a z-index and `Div2` is movable.

What I want to do is change the color of `Div1` when `Div2` is moved underneath it.

**How do I detect if Div2 is overlapping Div1 to apply those styles?**

I'd rather not use jQuery. I'm using Angular 2 - Rc4. And it is for a mobile app.

Comment: Put some code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below after getting details of div1 and div2 retrieved via getBoundingClientRect():

> var overlap = !(div1 .right < div2 .left || 
>                   div1 .left > div2 .right || 
>                   div1 .bottom < div2 .top || 
>                   div1 .top > div2 .bottom)